# Need regex to find \n or \r in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to search a string to see if there are any \n or \r characters in it.

If I set the regex to re.compile(r'(\n)') it works fine for finding \n. But, if I try to do the following re.compile(r'\\[nr]') or re.compile(r'\[nr]') to find either one, it doesn't work.

I understand the second one fails because the \[ escapes the bracket and makes it look for that. With the r'\[nr]' the pattern in the debugger (Visual Studio Code) shows the search pattern as '(\\\\[n])'. 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The regular expression tester at https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/6#python works fine with: (\[nr]).
thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think you need a regex at all? This sounds like an almost class "XY Problem", don't fall for that! BTW: Upgrade to Python 3!

Comment: Trying to learn regex and the company is using 2.7.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `[]` in regex it takes any characters within literally. However `\n` and `\r` are a two-character string representation of a single control character. What you want instead is `r'(\n|\r)'`

Answer (score 1):

Why regex?

```
crlf = set('\r\n')

def contains_cr_lf(text):
    """Returns True if text includes linefeeds or carriage returns as characters."""
    return any(x in crlf for x in text)

for t in ["Some text \t without: ","""Some text
with them: """]:
    print t, contains_cr_lf(t)
```

Result:

```
Some text    without:  False
Some text
with them:  True
```

Comment: Because I'm trying to learn regex and it's only a couple of lines to do the check.

Comment: @KernelSanders regex is usefull for many text-related problems - for this case I would use the function 2-liner

Answer (score 0):

`\r` and `\n` are character escapes, which means you can't split them around control characters in a regex. However, `r"([\r\n])"` works just fine.